# Obtain max length for a "string" column using LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to obtain the maximum column length for a VARCHAR, CHAR etc?

Comment: Do you want to know the max possible length for the columns, e.g. 1000 for varchar(1000) or the max length of values in this column?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way which avoids touching the database:

- Using Reflection, get the property of the entity class that corresponds to the column in question.
- Then, retrieve the System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column attribute of the property.
- Then, parse the DbType property of this attribute (eg **NVarChar(255) NOT NULL**) to get the column length.

Answer (score 1):

In pure T-SQL you can use this query:

```
select max_length from sys.columns as c inner join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id where o.name = 'myTable' and c.name = 'myColumn'
```

For linq-to-sql you need it rewrite into linq.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here:

[Linq to SQL - Underlying Column Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684/linq-to-sql-underlying-column-length)

Though I found it neater to change:

```
public static int GetLengthLimit(Type type, string field) //definition changed so we no longer need the object reference
//Type type = obj.GetType(); //comment this line
```

And call using:

```
int i = GetLengthLimit(typeof(Pet), "Name");
```

Can anybody think of a of way to strongly type the field reference?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int GetLengthLimit(Model.RIVFeedsEntities ent, string table, string field)
{
    int maxLength = 0;   // default value = we can't determine the length

    // Connect to the meta data...
    MetadataWorkspace mw = ent.MetadataWorkspace;

    // Force a read of the model (just in case)...
    // http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/quick-trick-for-forcing-metadataworkspace-itemcollections-to-load/
    var q = ent.Clients;
    string n = q.ToTraceString();

    // Get the items (tables, views, etc)...
    var items = mw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        if (i.Name.Equals(table, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // wrapped in try/catch for other data types that don't have a MaxLength...
            try
            {
                string val = i.Properties[field].TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value.ToString();
                int.TryParse(val, out maxLength);
            }
            catch
            {
                maxLength = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```